# How to config apache to resolve SSLSessionCache warning?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

When visit a site hosted by apache httpd, sometimes ok, sometimes unavailable.
The apache httpd log is as following:

`[Mon Sep 02 17:58:52 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations

[Mon Sep 02 17:59:06 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Mon Sep 02 17:59:10 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Mon Sep 02 17:59:10 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips configured -- resuming normal operations

[Mon Sep 02 18:00:06 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[Mon Sep 02 18:00:10 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]`

How to config apache httpd to solve this problem?

Comment: Err, take the hint and use the directive named in it? Off topic for SO.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to make sure you are correctly install nginx or gunicorn engine and propertly configured with mod_ssl.
     activate apache mod_ssl : sudo a2enmod ssl
     and open the nginx or gunicorn file setting the ssl_cache  before to get it works.
     one links to set the ssl_cache with nginx is: 
     http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache